# How can I perform git commit whenever I write a file in Vim?

Tags: git, vim

I'd like to accomplish the following goals:

1. Whenever I perform a writing file action in Vim, like `:w`, I'd like to add the snapshot of that file to the staging area and commit it to the local repo, just like I manually execute the commands `git add file.name && git commit -m 'some msg'`.
2. The local repo is not a problem, I'll initiate it manully, or better this vimscript will initiate the repo automatically for me when necessary.

How can I do this? Please advice, thanks!

Comment: I'd like to write some vimscripts to accomplish this, but I don't know how.

Comment: well, start by looking at `:h autocmd` or more specifically `:h BufWritePost`

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Committing each tiny change to every individual file in your repo with a generic commit message isn't the right way to use Git.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+commit+save

Comment: Don't.  If you want a versioning filesystem, use one.